# How to know the id of the dynamic link button?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  written a code to retrieve the id of the dynamic link button clicked by the user. But however, it is displaying all the link buttons' id.

Please check my code.

```
 if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                        JobDesignation = reader.GetString(0);
                        JobDescription = reader.GetString(1);
                        NoOfVacancies = Convert.ToString(reader.GetInt32(2));
                        DatePosted = Convert.ToString(reader.GetDateTime(3)).Replace("00:00:00", "");
                        jobId = reader.GetString(4);
                        int tblRows = 1;
                        int tblCols = 1;
                      
                        Table tbl = new Table();
                        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbl);
                        for (int i = 0; i < tblRows; i++)
                        {
                            readerrowcount = readerrowcount + 1;
                            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                            tr.CssClass = "rowStyle1";
                            for (int j = 0; j < tblCols; j++)
                            {
                                TableCell tc = new TableCell();
                                tc.CssClass = "cellStyle1";
                               System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label txtBox = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
                               txtBox.Text = "Job ID:" + jobId + "<br />" + "Job Designation:" + JobDesignation + "<br />" + "Job Description:" + JobDescription + "<br />" + "Vacancies:" + NoOfVacancies + "<br />" + "Ad Posted On:" + DatePosted + "<br />"+"";
                               tc.Controls.Add(txtBox);
                               tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                               System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton lbView = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton();
                               lbView.Text = "<br />" + "Apply for this Job";
                               
                               lbView.OnClientClick = "return RedirectTo('" + id + "');";
                               lbView.ID = "linkButton" + readerrowcount;
                               ID = readerrowcount;
                               
                               tc.Controls.Add(lbView);
                               tr.Cells.Add(tc);
                            

                            }
                          
                            tbl.Rows.Add(tr);

                            

                            string query = "INSERT INTO EmployeeJobTagging VALUES('" +ID + "','" + id + "','"+jobId+"','"+JobDesignation+"')";
                            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        ViewState["dynamictable"] = true; 
                      } reader.NextResult();
                    
                }
```

[image]

Here i have two rows displayed and if the user clicks on the first

- "apply for this job"

  i want the ID to be "1" to be passed to database so that there will be only 1 row inserted into the EmployeeJobTagging table. but here both the rows are inserted with ID= 1 and 2 respectively.

Please find below.

[image]

Kindly provide me some help.

Comment: Why do you `INSERT` when you load the records from database and create the controls dynamcially? I would do that only if the user clicked on the link. Where is this code located?

Comment: The linkButton's Click event is not firing at all. That is why i tried doing the above method.

Comment: lbView.Click was not at all firing.

Comment: It's not firing since you need to recreate all dynamically controls on every postback in `Page_Load` at the latest with the same ID as before. An event handler is **too late**. Why don't you use a web-databound control like `Repeater`? http://tinyurl.com/yfc66o

Comment: I don't have any idea of repeater.

Comment: @Chaithz - Repeater is very simple and easy to use, check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8f2zez5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You should try it.